# How to create a unique function with its own pointer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Calling getFunction will return a unique function every time, right?

```
var getFunction = function() {
    var myFunction = function() {
    };
    return myFunction;
}

var function1 = getFunction();
var function2 = getFunction();

function1 === function2; // false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every time a function is called, a new scope is created for that run and all variables defined in it are unique and not shared between runs of the function.

Even doing something like the following would have the same result as the inner function is still defined inside of the function's scope and can see the arguments to the outer function.

```
var getFunction = function() {
    function myFunction() {
    };
    return myFunction;
}

var function1 = getFunction();
var function2 = getFunction();

function1 === function2; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be visualized as follows. The outer scope holds the three variable allocations and the getFunction invocations will create two new scopes which return a function object defined in that scope.

[image: visualization of scope]